# Why does CUDA float program get faster in full speed FP64 mode?

Tags: performance, cuda, double, gpu

My CUDA program uses only `float`, `int`, `short` and `char` types in its computation. None of the input or output arrays have members of type `double`. And none of the kernels create any `double` type inside them during computation.

This program has been compiled using CUDA SDK 5.5 in Release mode using NSight Eclipse. A typical compile line looks like this:

```
nvcc -O3 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -M -o "src/foo.d" "../src/foo.cu"
```

I am running this program on a GTX Titan on Linux. To my surprise, I noticed that this program runs 10% faster when I enable the full speed FP64 mode on Titan. This can be done by enabling CUDA Double Precision option in NVIDIA X Server Settings program.

While I am happy for this free speed bonus, I would like to learn the reasons why a CUDA float program could get faster in FP64 mode?

Comment: Have you verified in the profiler that no DP operations are being performed? The counter appears under `CUDA Achieved FLOPS`.

Comment: @RogerDahl: In the metrics section, I enabled all the double related FLOPS options. After profiling, I see that all these double columns for all kernel invocations is zero. Full speed FP64 runs cores at slower clock, but not the memory clock I guess. Could this cause some speedup for certain type of kernels?

Comment: This is just speculation, but when you change the ratio between the clocks, you are very likely to change the order in which memory transactions are issued. Which again could affect the L1 and L2 hit rates.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that when you enable the full speed FP64 mode on Titan, more compute units start participating in computation and these FP64 compute units can be used to computing FP32. But enabling large amount of FP64 blocks also slowing clock, so computing getting faster by only 10%.

How to get 10%?
When Titan runs in 1/24 FP64 mode, it runs at 837MHz. When it runs in 1/3 FP64 mode, it runs at 725MHz. So (1+1/3)/(1+1/24) * 725/837 = 1.109.

References: http://www.anandtech.com/show/6760/nvidias-geforce-gtx-titan-part-1/4

I found confirmation my guess.

"What's more, the CUDA FP64 block has a very special execution rate: 1/1 FP32."

Reference http://www.anandtech.com/show/5699/nvidia-geforce-gtx-680-review/2

This information for GK104, Titan have GK110. But it's one architecture. So I think that GK110 also have this opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

**Titan cards by default have the FP64 implementation "capped"**, that has been done mainly due to power efficiency reasons and clockspeed.

NVIDIA deliberately chose not to enable this by default and instead let you control the behavior by setting FP64 at full speed (1/3 FP32) or reduced speed (1/24 FP32).

References: http://www.anandtech.com/show/6760/nvidias-geforce-gtx-titan-part-1/4

Comment: How does that speedup float computation in FP64 mode? On the contrary, it should slow it down, isn't it?

Comment: It depends on your workload: if your program uses a lot of double precision computations and you have fewer FP64 units you might really benefit from removing the cap.